# Mixing anaerobic or lactate threshold training and base aerobic training in the same workout

Tags: cardio, anaerobic, lactate-threshold

I typically have 1.5 hours available for a workout once a day. However I  can only really manage around 45 minutes of effective high intensity intervals or lactate threshold training in one session.

Is there a benefit in filling the remaining time with base aerobic training? Or is it a better use of that time to do strength training, or simply rest?

If there is value in combining different levels of aerobic, threshold + anaerobic exercise in the same session, what's a good way to structure it to get the most benefit?

Comment: This is the entire basis behind fartlek type runs, and many runners will do a few miles warmup/warmdown before interval sessions.